# Google Bar Chart grouped & stacked annotations issue

Tags: annotations, google-visualization, bar-chart

I am trying to show annotations for my google Bar chart that has a grouped and stacked data. I am not able to show the annotations, although I have added annotation roles in the data columns as described in google bar charts exam Following is my Google chart script:

```
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {
  packages: ["bar"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);


function drawStuff() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Users", "Normal", { role: 'annotation' }, "SLA", { role: 'annotation' }, "HP", { role: 'annotation' }, "SLA", { role: 'annotation' }],
    ["John D.", 3, '3', -2, '3', 1, '3', 0, '3'],
    ["Muhammad E.", 4, '3', -2, '3', 5, '3', -3, '3'],
    ["Steve B.", 5, '3', -3, '3', 1, '3', -1, '3'],
    ["Donna P.", 5, '3', -1, '3', 6, '3', -3, '3'],
    ["Altamash A.", 7, '3', -4, '3', 6, '3', -2, '3'],
    ["Uzair T.", 3, '3', -2, '3', 0, '3', 0, '3'],
    ["Mathew R.", 6, '3', -3, '3', 6, '3', 0, '3']
  ]);

  /* ----- */

  /* ---- */

/* Options Start */
  var options = {
    bars: "vertical",
    isStacked: 'true',
    width: "90%",
    height: 500,

    annotations: {
        textStyle: {
          color: 'black',
          fontSize: 11,
        },
        alwaysOutside: true
      },

    legend: {
      position: "top",
      alignment: "start"
    },

    hAxis: {
      title: '',
      textStyle: {color: '#777777', fontSize: '20', fontName: 'Overpass', bold: true},

    },

    vAxis: {
      textStyle: {color: '#fff'},
      title: '',
      gridlines: {
        color: "#eee"
      },
      viewWindow: {
        ticks: 20,
        max: 10
      }
    },
    vAxes: {
      0: {},
      1: {
        gridlines: {
          color: "transparent"
        }
      }
    },
    series: {
      0: {
         targetAxisIndex: 0,
         color: '#4285f4'
      },
      1: {
         targetAxisIndex: 0,
        color: '#93b6f3'
      },
      2: {
         targetAxisIndex: 1,
         color: '#db4437'
      },
      3: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1,
        color: '#f19a92'
      }
    },



  };
  /* Options End */
  /* Generating Graph */
  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[column roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles), including annotations, are not supported by *Material* charts

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) for the full list of unsupported options

recommend using a *Core* chart with the following option

```
theme: 'material'
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawStuff,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawStuff() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Users", "Normal", { role: 'annotation' }, "SLA", { role: 'annotation' }, "HP", { role: 'annotation' }, "SLA", { role: 'annotation' }],
    ["John D.", 3, '3', -2, '3', 1, '3', 0, '3'],
    ["Muhammad E.", 4, '3', -2, '3', 5, '3', -3, '3'],
    ["Steve B.", 5, '3', -3, '3', 1, '3', -1, '3'],
    ["Donna P.", 5, '3', -1, '3', 6, '3', -3, '3'],
    ["Altamash A.", 7, '3', -4, '3', 6, '3', -2, '3'],
    ["Uzair T.", 3, '3', -2, '3', 0, '3', 0, '3'],
    ["Mathew R.", 6, '3', -3, '3', 6, '3', 0, '3']
  ]);

  var options = {
    theme: 'material',
    isStacked: 'true',
    width: '90%',
    height: 500,
    annotations: {
      textStyle: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 11,
      },
      alwaysOutside: true
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      alignment: 'start'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: '',
      textStyle: {color: '#777777', fontSize: '20', fontName: 'Overpass', bold: true},
    },
    vAxis: {
      textStyle: {color: '#fff'},
      title: '',
      gridlines: {
        color: '#eee'
      },
      viewWindow: {
        ticks: 20,
        max: 10
      }
    },
    vAxes: {
      0: {},
      1: {
        gridlines: {
          color: 'transparent'
        }
      }
    },
    series: {
      0: {
         targetAxisIndex: 0,
         color: '#4285f4'
      },
      1: {
         targetAxisIndex: 0,
        color: '#93b6f3'
      },
      2: {
         targetAxisIndex: 1,
         color: '#db4437'
      },
      3: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1,
        color: '#f19a92'
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**note**: also recommend *not using* `jsapi` to load the library, use `loader.js`
according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

this only changes the `load` statement, see above snippet...

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat but I want to show the annotations on data set that can be grouped as well as stacked. As you can notice that I want to show the first two columns as stacked as group 1 and then next two columns stacked as group 2 for each single user.